# H1 tags for header image?

Tags: headers

In `heading.php` of the Leaf Theme there is the following code:

---

```
    <?php $header_image = get_header_image();
    if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
            <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" />
       </a>
    <?php } else { ?>
         <hgroup>
              <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
              <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
         </hgroup>

   <?php } ?>
```

I want to add a text to the header image and wrap that text into H1 tags for the homepage and h6 for all other pages. *The Else part doesn't have too much importance as I will only be using a image. I included it because it´s part of the code.*

I have tried for a while now but I simply don´t know enough of PHP to pull it off.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "add text to the header image"

Answer (score 3):

try is_front_page() conditional function

```
<?php } else { ?>
         <hgroup>
              <?php $is_front_page = is_front_page() ? 'h1' : 'h6'; ?>
              <<?php echo $is_front_page ?> class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
              <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
         </hgroup>

   <?php } ?>
```

### Edit

To address the OP's question about adding to the header image:

```
<?php $header_image = get_header_image();
if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
        <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" />
   </a>
   <?php 
   /* Start new code here */
   $heading = ( is_front_page() ? 'h1' : 'h6' );
   ?>
   <<?php echo $heading; ?>>INSERT TEXT HERE</<?php echo $heading; ?>>
   <?php 
   /* End new code here */ 
   ?>
<?php } else { ?>
```

Comment: The OP wanted to add new text to the first part of the header_image conditional. Since your `is_front_page()` approach is correct, I just added to your answer, rather than creating a second answer.